# Django Capturing only letters

Tags: django

I'm having trouble changing my URL which at the moment captures slug only and id . How can I change it to capture only words

```
    url(r'^cat/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+),(?P<id>\d+)/$', 
        'sd.views.cat',
        name ='cat'
    ),

  def sd(request, slug, id):
```

thank you for helping me

word only letters like hello , joshi not username

Comment: Please add examples of valid input

Comment: you should also remove that comma (",") in your url regex and replace it with a slash ("/").

Comment: @Yossi valid input? U mean example of words? Hello

Comment: What do you want to do in the function? What should the new word be called? Right now your view method is expecting both a `slug`, and `id`: `def cat(request, slug, id)`, which one of these should the "word" be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only letters (which composed words) in first parameter, you just have to ask `\w` in your slug, not `\d`:

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<slug>[-\w]+),(?P<id>\d+)/$', 
    'sd.views.cat',
    name ='cat'
),
```

(I didn't remove the - from the regex because I think it's an accepted char in your slugs. Also, your question wasn't very clear...)